# Looping through mysql array, populating a slider and I can't figure this out

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to populate this web design with MySQL and I can't figure out how to do it, I know how to do a simple `while loop` through associative array, but this seems very confusing.

My query string:

```
$recent_query = "SELECT * FROM RES WHERE ListAgentID='2752' ORDER BY ListDate LIMIT 4";
```

My while loop to fetch row

```
while ($rf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recent_result)) {
echo <<<RECENT
<div class="property-row">
  <article class="hentry has-featured">
    <div class="property-featured">
     ROW 1
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="hentry has-featured">
    <div class="property-featured">

    ROW 2
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="property-row">
  <article class="hentry has-featured">
    <div class="property-featured">
    ROW 3
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="hentry has-featured">
    <div class="property-featured">
    ROW 4
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

RECENT;
}
```

I cant figure out how to populate these 4 articles as separate mysql row. I want to query 4 rows and populate them inside the HTML. I just cant seem to do it. Please help. Thank you.

Here's an live example of the slider, under recent properties: http://html.nootheme.com/citilights/

Comment: what do you mean, 4 articles? each record you get from the query is an article?

Comment: The slider has 2 rows and 2 articles inside each row, so 4 articles. I just don't how I can make each article a separate mysql row.

Comment: Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not giving any information on your table, it's kind of hard to know how it looks like. But from what I can gather off your question, you have a table with the columns `ListAgentID` and `ListDate`, in addition to you article itself, which I'm going to *assume* is called something like `ListArticle`.

Right, so - you have a table that resembles the one below

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
|  ListAgentID |  ListDate   | ListArticle                   |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
| 2752         | 09/09/2015  | Contents of first article...  |
| 2752         | 05/09/2015  | Contents of second article... |
| 2752         | 01/09/2015  | Contents of third article...  |
| 2752         | 30/08/2015  | Contents of fourth article... |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

So when you query with `SELECT * FROM RES WHERE ListAgentID='2752' ORDER BY ListDate LIMIT 4` you'll get all the information stored in the last four entries in your table. This means that your `while`-loop has to be run *four* times in order to fetch them all. And because of this, your code can't be built the way it is.

The best alternative, in my opinion, would be to store the text you retrieve from your `ListArticle`-column (or whatever it's called in YOUR database) into different variables (using an array would do it), and then echo them out later on your page, as such:

```
$posts = array();
while ($rf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recent_result)) {
    array_push($posts, $row["ListArticle"]);
}
```

Then you'll just echo these variables out in your HTML like this

```
<article class="hentry has-featured">
    <div class="property-featured">
        <?php echo $posts[0]; ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

(Note that PHP starts counting from 0, not 1, so if you want the first element of your array (the one at the top of the list from the database), you have to `echo $posts[0]`.)

Then you just echo out `$posts[0]` up to `$posts[3]` where you want them!